# How to join two pyspark data frames on Arraytype operation?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two DataFrames, `A` and `B`. Each have a column called `'names'` and this column is `ArrayType(StringType())`.

Now I want to left join `A` and `B` on the condition that `A['names']` and `B['names']` have common elements.

Here is an example:

A:

```
+---------------+
|          names|
+---------------+
|['Mike','Jack']|
|      ['Peter']|
+---------------+
```

B:

```
+---------------+
|          names|
+---------------+
|['John','Mike']| 
|           null|
+---------------+
```

after the left join, I should have:

```
+---------------+---------------+
|        A_names|        B_names|
+---------------+---------------+
|['Mike','Jack']|['John','Mike']| 
|      ['Peter']|           null|
+---------------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case you have to `explode` the values- `explode` will produce one row per value in your arrays and then you can join them and reduce the final result back to your desired format.

In the code example, I exploded the names and joined the DataFrames on the newly created column (`B_names`).  Finally the result will be grouped by `"names"` to remove the produced duplicates.

For the group by aggregate function, you can use `pyspark.sql.functions.first()`, with the parameter `ignorenulls` set to True.

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, explode, first

test_list = [['Mike', 'Jack']], [['Peter']]
test_df = spark.createDataFrame(test_list, ["names"])

test_list2 =  [["John","Mike"]],[["Kate"]]
test_df2 = spark.createDataFrame(test_list2, ["names"])

test_df2 = test_df2.select(
    col("names").alias("B_names"),
    explode("names").alias("single_names")
)

test_df.select(col("names").alias("A_names"), explode("names").alias("single_names"))\
    .join(test_df2, on="single_names", how="left" )\
    .groupBy("A_names").agg(first("B_names", ignorenulls=True).alias("B_names")).show()
```

Result:

```python
+------------+------------+
|     A_names|     B_names|
+------------+------------+
|[Mike, Jack]|[John, Mike]|
|     [Peter]|        null|
+------------+------------+
```